# How long to train pyBrain?

Tags: python, pybrain

I have a basic NN set up that has 2 inputs, 3 neurons, and 1 output.

If I have approximately 4000 data points (i.e. 4000 rows of 2 inputs and 1 output) for training, how long should I anticipate `trainUntilConvergence()` to take.

Also can `trainUntilConvergence` happen in a thread while I also continually add data to the training DataSet(in another thread)?  For example I start with one datapoint in the dataset, start the training, and continually add more datapoints to the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should ask "How long train neural network to achieve good results". In many books about neural network you can read, that it depends on size of learning set and network structure. So make a test/benchmark and try to learn 10 epochs, 20 epochs and 50 epochs - and print results/errors for each case. There is a way, to do it automatically with validating/testing set, when testing/validating error is increasing during learning, then you should stop learning(because network starts to overlearning) - you achieved good generalization. Definitely you should read more about neural networks e.e. ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ.html

According to second answer, imho at current state of pybrain you cannot change DataSet during learning.